# I've been trying to solve this integral for expected value of exponential distribution

Tags: calculus, probability, statistics

$$\int x \, λe^{-λx} dx = \frac{1}λ $$

I tried solving this with integration by parts with: $$ u = x$$ $$ dv = λe^{-λx}$$
making

$$ du = 1$$ and
$$ v = -e^{-λx}$$

I keep deriving
$$ \frac{-e^{-λx}(λx - 1)}λ$$

if possible can someone guide me on how to solve this?

Comment: Before integration by parts, use substitution method: $m=-\lambda x$

Comment: You are expected to evaluate the **definite integral** from zero to infinity in order to get an expected value.

Comment: $\mathrm du=\mathrm dx$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not true that
\begin{align}
\int x\lambda e^{-\lambda x} dx=\frac{1}{\lambda}
\end{align}
However, it is true that
\begin{align}
\int_0^{\infty} x\lambda e^{-\lambda x} dx=\frac{1}{\lambda}
\end{align}
To compute the above integral (which is the mean of the exponential distribution with rate parameter $\lambda$) one indeed typically uses integration by parts, as you did.

Using integration by parts we obtain
\begin{align}
\int_0^{\infty} x\lambda e^{-\lambda x}=\left[-x e^{-\lambda x}\right]_0^{\infty} + \int_0^{\infty} e^{-\lambda x} dx = \left[-\frac{1}{\lambda} e^{-\lambda x}\right]_0^{\infty}=\frac{1}{\lambda}
\end{align}